# Sending HTML form to address bar

Tags: html, forms, field, address-bar

Is it possible to generate a form in html that allows the text that's input to be sent to the address bar?

Comment: Looking on the answers and the ambiguty you should edit the question to make it more clear what you strive to achieve, describe a possible use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is, you just make sure the forms METHOD is set to GET:

```
<form id="myForm" method="GET">
//Form Stuff
</form>
```

Take a [look here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) for more information

Comment: This appends it to the url, is there a way to replace the address bar contents with the submitted text?

Comment: Possibly - what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create a start page. I don't think it's possible to make the focus automatically be the address bar, so I'm hoping to provide a form where I can type any address and send it to the address bar.

Comment: I'm still not understanding you.  If you want to type in the address bar you do it, why would someone fill in a form? Perhaps provide more of an overview of your system?

Comment: I was trying to make a start page that automatically focuses on the address bar, so people can type a url right away. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Most browsers do this already - have you come across Chrome?  Also if you set the homepage to 'about:blank' the user will be provided with a blank screen on startup - with the only box being the Address Bar at the top

Answer (score 0):

Without any testing and going off the top of my head, this should do the trick (messily):

```
<form onsubmit="window.location = document.getElementById('addressfield').value; return false;">
   <input type="text" id="addressfield" />
</form>
```

Comment: Possibly could work - I just don't think you would ever need to do this